# dynamically creating push buttons in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, button, dynamic, push

i am trying to create a GUI in matlab, in which dynamically the buttons must be created.
i.e when the user selects the directory, as many number of buttons will be created as many number of files are there in the selected directory. How can one achieve that? any help will be seriously appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [handle graphics](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitoggletool.html) and more specifically the [handle-graphics components](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/adding-components-to-a-programmatic-gui.html#f15-1001532). From the same webpage you can see the code to create a button programmatically,

```
h = figure('ToolBar','none');
ht = uitoolbar(h);
a = rand(16,16,3);
htt = uitoggletool(ht,'CData',a,'TooltipString','Hello');
```

and also set their callback/handler properties as a property-value pair.